# How to give thickness to circle using solidify modifier?

Tags: solidify-modifier

This is what i'm doing, which is not giving the desired result:

I'm adding a circle using add>mesh>circle.
Then i'm selecting that circle and adding a solidify modifier, adjusting a thickness, but the thickness is not showing.

How do i use solidify modifier on the circle mesh.?

Comment: I can't remember if the circle primitive comes with a center face or not.  If there is no face, select all verts and fill with F.

Comment: It doesn't come filled so there's not really much point in trying to use a solidify modifier on it. Just extrude it if you want to add depth to the circle. Then you can solidify that.

Comment: It indeed doesn't come with faces by default. So either you fill it afterwards like explained by @AllenSimpson, or when you add the circle object: open the last operation menu in the bottom left corner and change the fill type https://i.imgur.com/zrh0ZdJ.jpeg

Comment: What the above comments say: the _Solidify_ modifier gives thickness to faces. The default circle primitive has no face, hence no thickness.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to fill the face and solidify it into a cylinder, or are you just trying to "thicken" the ring?